# Bootstrap: how to control size and color of a graphic icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am very new in using bootstrap. So my apologies in advance if the question is very basic. 
I am using bootstrap in my Angular application and would like to add a back button icon to the page, But what I am trying to do is to make the color of the icon gray instead of its original color and make its size bigger.

```
<a href="./material_view">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left" ></span>
</a>
```

For the list of graphics in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav, I have picked the graphic of class "glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left". 
I tried adding height and width to the span element but it didn't work. 
I was wondering if any one has any tips or suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, if you don't mind, you can change to the [Font Awesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io) (personally I had a lot of problems with glyphicons in the past).

The actual code would be:

HTML:

```
<a href="./material_view">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

And you can modify its CSS by simply calling its class:

CSS:

```
.icon{
    color: gray;
    font-size: 50px; //or whathever you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks G.Nachtigal. Can control the color so that the small arrow inside of the circle and its border becomes gray but the area inside of the circle becomes white, exactly the opposite of the current color?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can do that cause Font Awesome is treated like a simple character by css. Maybe you need another solution for this.